# usage of "all of the tasks" and "all the tasks"

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

which of the following sentences is the most common in English?

"**all of the tasks** were performed well."
"**all the tasks** were performed well."

Answer (score 3):

You can find this sort of thing out by searching corpora like [*The Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)*](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) or [*The British National Corpus (BNC)*](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/).  I searched for both strings in both corpora.  Here's what I found:

```
                      COCA    BNC
  all of the tasks     8       1
  all the tasks        42      12
```

So it seems that both phrases are used, but the shorter version is more common in both British and American English.   Before regular noun phrases like *the tasks*, they seem to be roughly interchangeable.

---

This agrees with in Swan's *Practical English Usage*, point 36, in which he says either *all* or *all of* can be used.  He notes, however, that before pronouns, *all of* is used.  He gives the following examples:

> **All of us** can come tomorrow.
>   She's invited **all of you**.

Note that the accusative form *us* is used, not the nominative *we*.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all%20of%20the%20tasks,%20all%20the%20tasks&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,all%20of%20the%20tasks;,c0;.t1;,all%20the%20tasks;,c0).

Both sentences are grammatically correct and semantically equivalent, but *all the tasks* is more common.

[image]

Comment: By the way, *n-gram* is a general term, and n-grams exist outside Google Books Ngram Viewer.  For this reason, I personally choose not to refer to their graphing tool as "Ngrams".

Comment: Good point, @snailplane. I tend to call things by their product name - Ngrams, in this case - but you're absolutely right that this can cause confusion or semantic shift in the language; e.g. tissue / Kleenex.

Answer (score 0):

Both are okay **but...** [GrammarMonster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/all_of.htm) describes it.

> All of the tasks were performed well - is not preferred. Because *tasks* is not a pronoun.

Very basic rule says that we **generally** use *all of* when the next word is a pronoun. For instance...

> All of 'you', all of 'us'

For normal nouns, we **generally** use just *all.*

> All the 'surgeons', all the 'soldiers', all the 'tasks' and so on.

Comment: am amazed with quick votes ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but now I know why they say, "Don't believe things you read on the Internet."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, in this site there are other reasons: http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/article4d.html would you please take a look.

Comment: @DamkerngT. OALD, Collins, British Council and **GrammarMonster** are on the internet. Not sure what to believe now when people start downvoting sources from the reputed sites *exclusively* made for grammar. :)

Comment: "All of the tasks were performed well" is just fine.

Comment: @snailplane many times, I refer GrammarMonster for its easy language and clear explanation. I really doubt for this reference in future now. Not offtopic on the comment though - which is the best site to refer? :)

Comment: @MaulikV Try PEU 36.

Comment: I have no idea.  I use books.

Comment: GrammarMonster even states on your linked page that both *all* and *all of* are acceptable when the following word is not a pronoun. I think the goal of their rule is to help learners avoid improper constructions such as *all us*, not educate on the finer points of grammar.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Do you see bolded *generally*? And also the phrase *very basic rule* in my answer? Anyway, *edited* to stay clear.

Comment: @MaulikV No, I hadn't refreshed the page. No need to be defensive.