# grammar using the word OF

Tags: prepositions, ellipsis, determiners

We are making a thank you sign for our donors. Regarding text: when thanking them do we say "we wish to thank all our donors" or is it "we wish to thank all of our donors"

Comment: Either is acceptable, and the only difference is one of rhythm.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["All of the ...." or " All the ... "?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/all-of-the-or-all-the) Also ['all' , 'all the', 'all of the', and 'the whole'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36721/), [usage of “all of the tasks” and “all the tasks”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23983/), and doubtless several others.

Answer (score 2):

Both forms are correct. However, *all of* is mostly used before pronouns (*us*, *them*,*...*) and *all* before nouns (e.g. *cows*, *chairs*). Please note that it is **a guideline**, not a rule. So if you wish to use *all of* instead of *all* before a noun for stylistic reasons, please do so.

Some examples:

> - *All of* the cows.
> - *All* cows.

Both forms are correct, but the one used in the second sentence is more commonly used.

This does not work for pronouns, those can be used with *all of*, but not with *all*:

> - *All of* us.
> - *All* us. (not gramatically correct)